# Transform an imageview programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I need to transform an imageview programmatically like this image:

[image]

I tried to do with the matrix object but I have not managed to do. Can anyone help or guide me?

Thank you so much!

**Update 1:**

This is the code where I could rotate the image using the matrix object but have not gotten a function to do what I want:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    matrix.postRotate(90, 200, 200);
    matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
    image.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: Instead of attempting to transform an `ImageView`, try to understand how to transform a `Bitmap`. When you'll get stuck, edit/expand the question.

Comment: no need to transform a Bitmap, what he needs is correct Matrix transformation e.g. by using Camera object

Comment: remember to set the ImageView's scaletype to Matrix!

Comment: I updated my question with some code using the Matrix.

Comment: @Yeray google for: android matrix camera perspective

Comment: @Yeray did you found any solution?